# Unable to login into Data Loader

Tags: data-loader

When I try to login into data loader, I get a login error. I am sure that I am using the correct username and password, but I am still unable to login.

Comment: What was the error message ?

Comment: Error logging into salesforce. Please check your username and password

Comment: you are login with developer org credentials or sandbox org credentials?

Comment: I am testing with a developer org

Comment: Do i need to change some settings on data loder?

Comment: yes you need to change  !! so under data loader setting check for server host ...is it https://login.salesforce.com ? 

if not then make it like above

Comment: You might be behind a proxy and need to specify that in settings

Answer (score 8):

The two most common problems are:

1. You need to either:

   - Add append a Security Token to the end of your password. The security token will be emailed to you if you reset it from **My Settings** > **Personal Information** in Salesforce.
   - Add your current ip address to your user profile. If you don't see the button to reset your security token, it is likely because your user profile has ip restrictions set up. If you go to **Setup** > **Manage Users** > **Profiles** > ***Your Profile*** > **Login IP Ranges**, you can add your ip address to the list, and you will be able to login to the Data Loader with just your username and password, without having to add a security token.
2. You are logging in to production or a developer environment instead of the sandbox (or vice-versa) and you need to change the target url to login.salesforce.com (or test.salesforce.com) in the data loader settings.

Comment: How about adding a 3rd - failing to append the security token to the password?

Comment: @KeithC That was part of my #1. Being at a white-listed ip range can "make up" for not having a security token, so since you only need one or the other, I put them together as a single issue.

Comment: Woops I should have read the whole sentence. Or the sentence should start with adding the security token.

Comment: @KeithC good point. It would make sense to lead off with the security token.

Answer (score 3):

When using the Data Loader, you need to set the server host to be:

1. https://login.salesforce.com for **Production** and **Developer** environments, or
2. https://test.salesforce.com for **Sandbox** environments.

You can find this under **Settings**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are facing this error "Failed to send request to https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/31.0", then add proxy details if you are using private domain as shown below screenshot
[image: dataloader proxy]

Answer (score 0):

Probably silly but the password has to be password + security token.

Thanks

Comment: I tried everything but that did not work either

Answer (score 0):

I got the same/similar issue as while trying to connect to salesforce using Apex Dataloader.

Got a total of 2 issues while trying to connect, after resolving the first one.

1. Error "*Error logging in to Salesforce. Please check your username and
   password.*"
2. Error" *TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https*"

**1) For the 1st issue please do below**
You will need to reset your security token before following the instructions below.  To reset your security token click Setup > My Personal Information > Reset My Security Token.  Then click the "Reset Security Token" button on the resulting page.  After that you will receive an email with your security token and some instructions very similar to these...
How to enter your security token:
If your password = "mypassword"
And you security token = "XXXXXXXXXX"
You must enter "mypasswordXXXXXXXXXX" in place of your password
Remember that these security tokens are for tools like the data loader but not for use on the standard Salesforce.com login page.

**2)For the 1st issue please do below**
Need to deactivate the "Require TLS 1.1 or higher for HTTPS connections" under **critical updates** in Salesforce.
Please follow the instructions provided by salesforce itself [Clik_here](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000232847&language=en_US)

After this I was able to Export/Import records in & out of Salesforce without any issue