# Unable to connect to hostname 'test.salesforce.com' with given login credentials

Tags: force.com

I am trying to create Force.com project with Eclipse but It's not successful.

Can anybody help me!
[image]

Comment: You're going to need the security token.

Comment: Or white-list your ip adress on the user profile.

Comment: so solution is just type random "Security Token", Nick?

Comment: @DucNguyen it is a randomly generated value, but it has to be that one particular value for your user.

Comment: @Martin, thanks, but sorry, I'm very new about Salesforce. I don't know where to start, where to create my first Force.com even just "Hello Word!" project....I am Zend developer before.

Comment: related: [Unable to login to dataloader](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91447/unable-to-login-into-data-loader/91448#91448)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Nick's comment already told you that you need to input your security token, I guess you are still confused about how to find it.

If no one in your current team knows your security token, which I believe is your current situation, just reset it. To do this, follow this guide: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=user_security_token.htm . Then you can use this security token for your Eclipse login.