# Unable to Authenticate Login with Salesforce Data Loader CLI Using Custom Domain

Tags: data-loader, authentication, force-cli

I have scoured the internet looking for a solution that seems is extremely common among users looking to connect to Salesforce via Data Loader CLI.

On top of reading just about every forum out there including this [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91447/unable-to-login-into-data-loader)

I am unable to effectively connect to my Salesforce account (Production) to extract data.

At our company we use a custom domain to login:

```
companyname.cloudforce.com
```

Using the encryption.bat I have created a encrypted password, but alas, it does not work.

I have tried my password alone and password+security token.

I have reset my token to retry the entire process.

I am not sure if this affects the login process via API, but usually when approached with a connector widget to salesforce (the UI interface looking like this:)

[image]

We click on the custom domain link at the bottom right where we input:

```
ourcompanyname.cloudforce.com
```

Upon where I am greeted by this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This is the username by which we use to login to our computers. Example:

```
username: myname
password: mypassword
```

However, this is slightly different when I login straight from a web browser where upon my login credentials then changes too:

```
username: myname@mycompany.com
password: mypassword
```

Either way, I have tried both ways for my login credentials for the Data Loader CLI and neither one worked.

I am completely lost and have no idea what to do next. If anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

BIG EDIT***

I am successful by logging in using Data Loader GUI and forces me to use the login procedure as described by the pictures above. I connect fine and am able to manipulate data. So if it works via the GUI is must work via the CLI, but I am just lost as to how to go about this.

** second edit:
I am unsure if this will help any, but I will post my process-conf.xml:

```xml
<beans>
    <bean id="TicketExport" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
        <description>Ticket Export.</description>
        <property name="name" value="TicketExport"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Users\duys\Documents\Tableau\Salesforce\data\outbound\Ticket.csv"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.readUTF8" value="true"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.writeUTF8" value="true"/>
                <entry key="process.enableExtractStatusOutput" value="true"/>
                <entry key="process.enableLastRunOutput" value="true"/>
                <entry key="process.lastRunOutputDirectory" value="C:\Users\duys\Documents\Tableau\Salesforce\status\log"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
                <entry key="process.statusOutputDirectory" value="C:\Users\duys\Documents\Tableau\Salesforce\status\log"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.bulkApiCheckStatusInterval" value="5000"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.bulkApiSerialMode" value="5000"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessages" value="true"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.debugMessagesFile" value="C:\Users\duys\Documents\Tableau\Salesforce\status\debug.txt" />
                <entry key="sfdc.enableRetries" value="true"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://mycompany.cloudforce.com"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="FX5__Ticket__c"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="500"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value=[SOQL QUERY STRING]/>
                <entry key="sfdc.insertNulls" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="100"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.maxRetries" value="3"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.minRetrySleepSecs" value="2"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.noCompression" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="my encrypted password +/-security token"/>
                <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="C:\Users\duys\Documents\Tableau\Salesforce\key.txt" />
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="60"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.useBulkApi" value="false"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="duys@pioneeres.com"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Anyone........? :(